# JavaScript Search bar producing error on pagedart and codepen confirmed code

Tags: javascript, search, full-text-search

I am a begginer, as of JavaScript is concerned and am building a search bar. I have the following JavaScript for the search bar:

```
const f = document.getElementById('form');
const q = document.getElementById('query');
const google = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3A+';
const site = 'example.com';

function submitted(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const url = google + site + '+' + q.value;
  const win = window.open(url, '_blank');
  win.focus();
}

f.addEventListener('submit', submitted);
```

I have checked this code from [pagedart](https://pagedart.com/blog/how-to-add-a-search-bar-in-html/) and their blog has almost a similar JavaScript. Also Codepen confirms that the [code (on codepen)](https://codepen.io/pagedart/pen/VwvzEbx) has no error

I am unable to understand the problem in it, as it returns TypeError: cannot read property "focus" of null.

Here's the snippet I used it in:

```js
const f = document.getElementById('form');
const q = document.getElementById('query');
const google = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3A+';
const site = 'example.com';

function submitted(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const url = google + site + '+' + q.value;
  const win = window.open(url, '_blank');
  win.focus();
}

f.addEventListener('submit', submitted);
```

```css
  #form {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-style: inset;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    align-items:center;
  }

  #query {
    all: unset;
    font: 16px;
    color: #000;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 6px 10px;
  }
  svg {
    color: #000;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    padding: 10px;
  }

  button {
    all: unset;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
  }
```

```html
<form role="search" id="form">
  <input type="search" id="query" name="q" placeholder="Search..." aria-label="Search through site content">
  <button id="search">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" class="search-icon"><path class="path1" d="M848.471 928l-263.059-263.059c-48.941 36.706-110.118 55.059-177.412 55.059-171.294 0-312-140.706-312-312s140.706-312 312-312c171.294 0 312 140.706 312 312 0 67.294-24.471 128.471-55.059 177.412l263.059 263.059-79.529 79.529zM189.623 408.078c0 121.364 97.091 218.455 218.455 218.455s218.455-97.091 218.455-218.455c0-121.364-103.159-218.455-218.455-218.455-121.364 0-218.455 97.091-218.455 218.455z"></path></svg>
  </button>
</form>
```

Please help me through this code...

Comment: 50 views and no answers or comments?! Why?

Comment: You never told us what the error is.

Comment: @takendarkk The question has been edited today. The error was always mentioned. I'll re mention it..

Comment: It meas `win` was null. You need to confirm that the window was actually opened which doesn't seem to have happened.

Comment: The window does open in codepen: https://codepen.io/pagedart/pen/VwvzEbx

Comment: Then you need to do your debugging in the environment where the error actually occurs.

Comment: @takendarkk This seems to happen only on SO. Is this a problem with the snippets?

Comment: If the problem only happens on SO, then what prompted you to start asking the question in the first place?

Comment: I noted it after your comment, @takendarkk